# Redirect to specific pages depending upon the url routing using htaccess file

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the urls like

```
http://localhost/mis  
http://localhost/mis/newsletter.php  
http://localhost/mis/cms.php?mainid=65  
http://localhost/mis/news.php?mainid=93
```

Well I am using these urls for **school** section.

Now for the **A-level** section I have the following urls

```
http://localhost/mis/index.php?mode=0  
http://localhost/mis/newsletter.php?mode=0  
http://localhost/mis/cms.php?mainid=65&mode=0  
http://localhost/mis/news.php?mainid=93&mode=0
```

I want the above urls to be routed like

```
http://localhost/mis/a-level  
http://localhost/mis/a-level/newsletter.php  
http://localhost/mis/a-level/cms.php?mainid=65  
http://localhost/mis/a-level/news.php?mainid=93
```

Please help me out with these url routing via .htaccess file.

**EDIT:** The htaccess file is under mis folder

**FILE STRUCTURE:**

```
root>>
    mis>>
        .htaccess
        newsletter.php
        cms.php
        news.php
```

Comment: Is mode=0 relevant on every link as you've shown in your example, or is it only in certain cases?  If it is common, it seems silly to pass it as a variable every time when it could be more simply defined in several other ways.

Comment: @bpeterson76 . . I have different menus for school section and A-level section. This mode=0 separates A-level Section and defines menus different from school section. I have worked out for long on this pattern but i couldn't succeed. Finally I got the alternative to this. But this still doesn't satisfy me. You can browse http://misktm.edu.np for school section and http://misktm.edu.np/a-level for A-level section. You can find different menus for different section here. But I have to change the url pattern for A-level unlike the one I want to use.

Comment: THANKS FOR THAT CLARITY on you architecture!!! Would have been better to know all of this !@#$ 2 days ago.

Comment: @Dawson . . Sorry for the late edit because i was busy all these days. . And don't worry, I will again put this question in bounty unless and until I will get an exact solution.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try these in the *.htaccess* file inside the `/mis` folder.

```
# turning rewrite on
RewriteEngine On

# this will redirect: mis/a-level
RewriteRule ^a-level$ index.php?mode=0 [L]

# this will redirect all the rest
RewriteRule ^a-level/(.+)$ $1?mode=0 [QSA,L]
```

I think the lines like `http://localhost/mis/cms.php?mainid=65&amp;mode=0` are just copy-paste errors and you ment: `http://localhost/mis/cms.php?mainid=65&mode=0`

I have tested these rules. If they don't work on your system there must be some configuration issue. Are there other rewrite rules in your file? I not, try enabling rewrite logging to get some more information. This must be enabled in *httpd.conf* (they are not allowed in *.htaccess*).

```
RewriteLog D:\bence\wamp\logs\rewrite.log
RewriteLogLevel 3
```

My rewrite log for the url `http://proba.test/mis/a-level/news.php?some=thing&other=33`

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#f67a88/initial] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] add path info postfix: D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/a-level -> D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/a-level/news.php
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#f67a88/initial] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/a-level/news.php -> a-level/news.php
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#f67a88/initial] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] applying pattern '^a-level$' to uri 'a-level/news.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#f67a88/initial] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] add path info postfix: D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/a-level -> D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/a-level/news.php
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#f67a88/initial] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/a-level/news.php -> a-level/news.php
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#f67a88/initial] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] applying pattern '^a-level/(.+)$' to uri 'a-level/news.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#f67a88/initial] (2) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] rewrite 'a-level/news.php' -> 'news.php?mode=0'
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#f67a88/initial] (3) split uri=news.php?mode=0 -> uri=news.php, args=mode=0&some=thing&other=33
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#f67a88/initial] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] add per-dir prefix: news.php -> D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/news.php
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#f67a88/initial] (2) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] strip document_root prefix: D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/news.php -> /mis/news.php
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#f67a88/initial] (1) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] internal redirect with /mis/news.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#253ab08/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/news.php -> news.php
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#253ab08/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] applying pattern '^a-level$' to uri 'news.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#253ab08/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/news.php -> news.php
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#253ab08/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] applying pattern '^a-level/(.+)$' to uri 'news.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:36:03 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#253ab08/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] pass through D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/news.php
```

And the log for: `http://proba.test/mis/a-level`

```
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:39:29 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#25f6338/initial] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/a-level -> a-level
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:39:29 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#25f6338/initial] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] applying pattern '^a-level$' to uri 'a-level'
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:39:29 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#25f6338/initial] (2) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] rewrite 'a-level' -> 'index.php?mode=0'
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:39:29 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#25f6338/initial] (3) split uri=index.php?mode=0 -> uri=index.php, args=mode=0
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:39:29 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#25f6338/initial] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] add per-dir prefix: index.php -> D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:39:29 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#25f6338/initial] (2) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] strip document_root prefix: D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/index.php -> /mis/index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:39:29 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#25f6338/initial] (1) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] internal redirect with /mis/index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:39:29 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#260c1d0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:39:29 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#260c1d0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] applying pattern '^a-level$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:39:29 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#260c1d0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] strip per-dir prefix: D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/index.php -> index.php
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:39:29 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#260c1d0/initial/redir#1] (3) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] applying pattern '^a-level/(.+)$' to uri 'index.php'
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Mar/2011:11:39:29 +0100] [proba.test/sid#713440][rid#260c1d0/initial/redir#1] (1) [perdir D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/] pass through D:/bence/www/proba.test/mis/index.php
```

Comment: That is arguably the first good working solution of this question. +1

Comment: It does not remove "mode=0" from the query string, which seems to be one of the bullets of OPs wish list.

Comment: I understand that the question was the other way around.

Comment: @vbence . . Let me try these rules first, then i will make some comments . . Well actually I was in rush yesterday so didn't notice the whole grammatical errors . . :)

Comment: @vbence . . Well, I have just tried the rules . . Both the rules didn't work . .  I wonder who voted for this answer . . Literally these rules must work . . I did the same initially but didn't work in the project . .

Comment: May be i've mistenrstood your question. I thnink that you want to **hide** `mode=0` from the users and use the virtual directory: `a-level` **insted**. Am I correct? This code does just that.

Comment: @vbence . . Yes, you got me exactly . . and the rules also do the same literally . . But I wonder why those rules don't work for my project . . As I told you before too I did follow the same rules initially but couldn't make the project work . . And I was seeking for the solution here . .

Comment: @coosal Tried out the rules myself and added rewrite logs to help figure outwhere your system is stuck.

Comment: @vbence . . dude . . I have no doubt with your perfection . . I really appreciate your effort . . I just can't implement the rules in my project . . Well ..  no worries. . you are the one with satisfying answer bro . . :))

Comment: @coosal Thanks! :) Don't give up. The asnwer could be as simple as you don't have `mod_rewrite` enabled, or an other rule overriding these.

Comment: @vbence - perhaps the configuration issue is the other way around...I have a fresh apache2 install with php/mod_rewrite enabled. Your rules don't work in my system (404 errors), but mine do. So I'm wondering if additional features need to be enabled to get your rules to work. What could those be?

Comment: @Dawson This is a fresh install from wampserver.com (just enabled mod_rewrite) - I commented at your answer why the difference.

Comment: @vbence - that's AWESOME!. Your explanation is what I needed to see. Your rules work fine in my configuration as well. I threw a quick (if mode=0, tell me) into one of my scripts - worked like a charm. Makes perfect sense now. Nice job +1 from me. @coosal - thanks again for the experience.

Comment: @Dawson Thx for the upvote! I used `<?php print_r($_GET);` to make sure additional parameters arrive as well :)

Answer (score 0):

Got it...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)mode(.*)$
RewriteRule mis/(.*) /mis/a-level/$1?%1 [R]
```

Architecture for reference:

```
/root/
    .htaccess
    /mis/
        /a-level/
            newsletter.php
            cms.php
            news.php
```

`localhost/mis/newsletter.php?mainid=65&mode=0`

now redirects to

`localhost/mis/a-level/cms.php?mainid=65` - - (MODE BE GONE) :-)

No php required for param/value stripping. Pretty neat trick, if you can keep your Cond/Rules and RegEx under control. (note: an almost identical Cond/Rule may need to go directly ahead of this solution to catch the index.php file)

You can actually change the param/values as well:

```
RewriteRule mis/(.*) /mis/a-level/$1?blue=9 [R]
```

Had some help http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteQueryString

Comment: @Dawson, thanks for the effort. But I haven't got the actual solution for this problem yet. mode=0 can be stripped by php but php alone can't handle the url with a-level in the same fashion like I mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Dawson . . I still don't think you have understood the question and the condition yet.

Comment: @Dawson Yes you got it... from my answer. But still a bit off.

Comment: @Dawson . . a-level is not a folder . . Actually, htaccess has to create the folder on air virtually.

Comment: @Clodoaldo - I DIDN'T USE YOUR Answer - I READ THE MANUAL...THEN THE WIKI. I don't see any solutions here that are working, and when I finally found something that did work...based on a snippet conversation to change an original post...I get the caveat (It's not a folder, try again.) THANKS for the down vote. The hours I spent working and caring about this are done. peace

Comment: @Dawson I didn't downvote your post. It looks like someone downvoted all posts. Yes that "it's not a folder" is a motive to downvote the very badly explained question and I just did it.

Comment: @Clodoaldo - Thank you. Sorry. I've spent hours (literally) on this one. I found it intriguing - prob too much. If nothing else, I gained a ton of knowledge about mod_rewrite...more than I'll need in the foreseeable future. :-|

Comment: @Clodaldo . . I don't think it's a very badly explained question. . And it's a usual thing that as a developer you don't repeat the same codes for the common purpose rather you reuse the code for the repeated task. . And I did the same . . 
@Dawson . . I didn't downvote you either . . I guess somebody is being too personal with this . . I wonder why ? ?

Comment: @Dawson I think you got the problem the other way around. `localhost/mis/a-level/cms.php?mainid=65` is what the **user sees** and `localhost/mis/cms.php?mainid=65&mode=0` is what has to be called in the background. They currently use addresses like `localhost/mis/cms.php` so the php's reside in the mis directory. `a-level` does not exist it is just a user-friendly form instead of `mode=0`. So your answer and mine do exactly the opposite thing.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^a-level$ a-level/
RewriteRule a-level/(.*)$ $1?mode=0 [QSA]
```

The first rule acts as support for the second one, since the second one needs the trailing slash. You could also add `[R=301,L]` to the first rule to redirect the user to the version with the slash. (For real, actual folders, Apache will do just that, automatically. Since this is not a "real" folder you'd have to do it yourself.)

The second rule will simply strip the a-level part of the URL. The secret sauce, however, that makes this dish so low-calorie, is the QSA part. QSA stands for query string append. It will simply jams any existing query string to the end of the URL.

This has the added benefit that you make no assumptions about the contents of the QS. If you'd ever need to add another query variable, apart from mainid, you don't need to modify the rule.

Edit: Or, like this, if the htaccess file is in the web root.

```
RewriteRule ^mis/a-level$ mis/a-level/
RewriteRule mis/a-level/(.*)$ /mis/$1?mode=0 [QSA]
```

Comment: @nitro2k01 . . dude, your both rules don't work. Please read the question and the conditions carefully and reply me.

Comment: Hmmm? Did you even try them? I did, and they worked. I'm assuming that when the user enters http://localhost/mis/a-level/cms.php?mainid=65 , http://localhost/mis/cms.php?mainid=65&mode=0 should be executed, right? That's what my rule does. Perhaps you didn't add RewriteEngine On... I left it out because I thought it was obvious. I've added it to the answer. Without it, none of the rules are even processed. And of course, this .htaccess is meant to be in the mis directory.

Comment: @nitro2k01. . I am asking for rewrite rules . . Doesn't that mean i know something about mode_rewrite and it's rules like Rewrite Engine On and other .. ? ? I don't complain without any research . . Please do lots of research on this then comment . . Moreover please undo the downvote you did to @Matt . . Atleast his one rule did work . .

Comment: I have tested my rules and Matt's rules side-by-side, and they both work fine (except for the one of Matt's rules that doesn't work.) If it doesn't work, it has to do with your setup. Maybe you should tell us more about it? Where is the .htaccess that you are adding these rules to? Are there other .htaccess files? Maybe you need to add Options +FollowSymLinks?

Comment: Maybe the problem was that the .htaccess file was in the web root and not in the mis directory. (I told you in the first comment...) I edited the answer to include an alternative if the .htaccess is in the root.

Comment: Oh, and about Matt's answer... It's true that it "almost" worked for you. However, this is not just about you. It's about public education too. If someone looks at his answer, they may think that something like RewriteRule xxx?id=(.*)$ can work. It can't, since RewriteRule can't match that part of the URL. Maybe I'm saving someone from a headache in the future, if they find this page. If Matt fixes that problem, I will of course remove the bad rating.

Comment: @nitro2k01 . . dude, sorry to hurt you with my rude words. But I have placed the htaccess file in the root directory of mis folder. And, I haven't used any other htaccess file in any subfolders. Lastly your both rules didn't work. Now will you please help me with this ? ?

Comment: I'm out of ideas... Can you show me exactly what your .htaccess looks like now and exactly how my rules don't work? Do you get a 404 or something else? The more I know the better I can help you.

Comment: Neither of your rules redirect to desired page rather they produce 404 error. You can check the site http://misktm.edu.np for school section and http://misktm.edu.np/a-level for a-level section. And the htaccess content is as follow:
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule a-level/gallery/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)$ gallery.php?mainid=$1&start=$2&mode=0 [L]
RewriteRule a-level/events/([0-9]*)$ events.php?event_id=$1&mode=0 [L]
RewriteRule a-level/(.*)/([0-9]*)$ $1.php?mainid=$2&mode=0 [L]
RewriteRule a-level/(.*)$ $1.php?mode=0 [L]
RewriteRule a-level$ index.php?mode=0 [L]

Comment: But i want the urls to be rewritten like i asked in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{query_string} mode=0
RewriteRule mis/(.+?\.php)$ mis/a-level/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking at this the wrong way - your main problem is translating what the PHP code needs into something that is descriptive for the URL, rather than try and accomplish this via mod_rewrite, I suggest you reconsider your approach.

Using mode=0 is meaningless within the code, and is not obvious to anyone reading the code as to what it does. I suggest changing the code to accept mode=a-level instead. this will make your mod_rewrite rule far easier, and also make your code much easier to read.

Comment: Well, mode = 0 or mode = a-level has identical function. So no worries for that . . I am really concerned about the url pattern. . Please, any suggestion ? ?

Comment: excatly, identical function, but much more readable code. using mod_rewrite to change the format of the URL should be much easier too than translating 0 into a-level.

Comment: Well I am here for the solution not for fighting. .

Comment: Coosal - there was no fighting, I was just making a suggestion on how to solve your problem. There is no need to down vote it just because it isnt exactly what you were looking for.

Comment: . I want the rules not only the verbal suggestion dude . . :)

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tested it on a live server, but http://www.regextester.com/ shows these output what you need

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule a-level/(.*)\.php\?mainid=(.*)$ /mis/$1.php?mainid=$2&mode=0
RewriteRule a-level/(.*)\.php$ /mis/$1.php?mode=0
RewriteRule a-level$ /mis/index.php?mode=0
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. But the rule only worked is the following one: RewriteRule a-level$ /mis/index.php?mode=0

Comment: @coosal; typo in the escaping

Comment: Could you clarify me about that?

Comment: Matt's first rule won't work. The reason is that RewriteRule can't match query strings. It will strictly search the "path" part of the URL. If you need to match something specific in a querystring you can use e.g. RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} However, that's not necessary for your particular problem – see my answer.